# Simple C++ OpenSSL code crashing

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I'm working through a tutorial on using OpenSSL and when I try something rather basic
it seems to crash.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
    SSL * ssl;

    if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, NULL, "/etc/ssl/certs"))
    {
        /* Handle failed load here */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because you didn't call `SSL_library_init()`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  It seems that the tutorial missed that point!